# Sending 'DELETE' request to URL Response Code : 403 in java

Tags: java, httprequest

I want to delete the API from url : "http://dublr024vm.devlab.ibm.com:60633/B2BiAPIs/svc/cadigitalcertificates/_id:tibco_ssl" , I am getting java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL. I have passed the correct authentication details too.

Below is the part of my code:

```
public static void call_me() throws Exception {

    InputStream is = null;

    String url = "http://dublr024vm.devlab.ibm.com:60633/B2BiAPIs/svc/cadigitalcertificates/_id:tibco_ssl";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.29 Safari/537.36");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    System.setProperty("http.agent", "Chrome");
    // optional default is DELETE
    con.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

    byte[] message = "admin:password".getBytes("UTF-8");
    String encoding = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(message);
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+new String(encoding));

    con.connect();
    is = obj.openConnection().getInputStream();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'DELETE' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line, responseText = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        responseText += line;
    }
    br.close();
    con.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: You don't "delete the API" - you're sending request to delete a resource. `403` response code means you aren't allowed to. That's about everything I can tell you about that, you need to provide more details. This code you've added doesn't tell us what's on the other side and why you don't have permissions for delete requests.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But for accessing the APIs, I have provided the authentication, username:password. Using it in browser I am able to delete the API.